# manyfoot: Text Before New Footnote Group

Tags: footnotes, manyfoot

I am using the `manyfoot` package to work with multiple footnote numbering schemes in the same document. This works fine; however, I would like to have some kind of headline before the listing of the footnotes of one group (= same numbering scheme) on each page begins; here is an example for better understanding:

[image: Example of a headline for all footnotes of one group.]

I implemented this by defining a custom footnote rule for this particular group using the `\SelectFootnoteRule{}` command. This is a quick-and-dirty solution, because LaTeX expects footnote rules to occupy zero vertical space. Since this approach inserts an additional line, the "footnote rule" has now a vertical dimension and overfull `\vbox`` warnings are thrown.

I prepared the following MWE to demonstrate this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{manyfoot}
\newcommand{\Afootnoterule}{}
\SelectFootnoteRule{A}[\noindent\footnotesize Custom Footnotes:\vspace{2mm}]
\DeclareNewFootnote{A}[roman]

\begin{document}

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed fermentum 
    viverra\footnote{Normal footnote 1.} lobortis eu, facilisis nec elit. 
    Morbi fringilla, neque eu venenatis cursus\footnoteA{Custom footnote 1.},
    risus ante aliquam magna, nec consectetur est\footnote{Normal footnote 
    2.} sapien non orci. Nulla eu turpis ultrices, cursus libero vel, 
    placerat enim. Aliquam ac mi metus. Sed quis ultricies nisl. Etiam non 
    gravida orci. Donec tellus lacus, elementum a lobortis eu, facilisis nec
    elit.

    \lipsum[52-60]

    \clearpage

    Nulla feugiat magna eros\footnoteA{Just a custom footnote.} vehicula 
    lectus in justo fringilla euismod.

    \lipsum[13-20]

\end{document}
```

I am sure there is a correct way to insert these headings in such a way that abusing the `\SelectFootnoteRule{}` command is not necessary and `---` as a side effect `---` overfull `\vbox`es are not occurring any more. Can anybody help? Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't think `manyfoot` provides hooks other than what you are using. To reduce `\vbox`es you can use `\SelectFootnoteRule[1]{A}[\noindent\footnotesize \smash{Custom Footnotes:}\vspace{2mm}]`. If you want the text for each footnote, then use `\SetFootnoteHook{\noindent\footnotesize Custom Footnotes:\quad}`

Answer (score 1):

May be what you need

Edit (correction)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{manyfoot}
\newcommand{\Afootnoterule}{\noindent\mtbox{\footnotesize Custom Footnotes:}}
\newcommand{\mtbox}[1]{%
\raisebox{0pt}[0pt][2mm]{\parbox{\textwidth}{#1}}}
\SelectFootnoteRule{A}%[]

\DeclareNewFootnote{A}[roman]

\begin{document}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed fermentum 
    viverra\footnote{Normal footnote 1.} lobortis eu, facilisis nec elit. 
    Morbi fringilla, neque eu venenatis cursus\footnoteA{Custom footnote 1.},
    risus ante aliquam magna, nec consectetur est\footnote{Normal footnote 
    2.} sapien non orci. Nulla eu turpis ultrices, cursus libero vel, 
    placerat enim. Aliquam ac mi metus. Sed quis ultricies nisl. Etiam non 
    gravida orci. Donec tellus lacus, elementum a lobortis eu, facilisis nec
    elit.

    \lipsum[52-60]

    \clearpage

    Nulla feugiat magna eros\footnoteA{Just a custom footnote.} vehicula 
    lectus in justo fringilla euismod.

    \lipsum[13-20]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I am afraid this does not solve the issue. I don't want to abuse the `\SelectFootnoteRule` command; I'd rather like to have some patch/extension to the `manyfoot` package which introduces a new command, e.g. `\SelectFootnoteHeadline`, reserving proper space in the footnote block for the additional line(s).

Comment: @DigNative what about the updated ansower (\SelectFootnoteRule is some what like \selectfont)

Comment: Unfortunately, this does still not work. If you look at the third page, you will notice that the headline for the custom footnotes is missing. Additionally, I still get overfull boxes for the footnotes. I am pretty sure that a solution based on `\SelectFootnoteRule` will *never* work. In order to introduce such headlines, proper space has to be reserved in the footnote block, see the implementation of the `manyfoot` package for example.

Comment: In order to reserve more space for the footnote block devoted to footnotes of level `A` you could increase `\skip\footinsA`.  I cannot formulate a full answer now, but maybe this hint could help you in some way.  NOTES: 1) A most unfortunate lapse had previously led me to write `\dimen\footinsA` instead; this was really confusing, I apologize.  2) I realized, however, that this idea is foolish, since _manyfoot_ will add `\skip\footinsA` only if a previous, and different, footnote block is already present on the same page.  (This comment will be removed altogether in 24 hours or so.)